# Update value based on text box "enter" key hit

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Basically, I have a lot of text boxes that will be holding minimum and maximum values for a variable, I would like it so when I hit enter on one text box, it will "commit" the value (without losing focus of the box).

Is this possible?

These are the boxes that I am currently running (copy the format about 10 more times)

```
        <!-- Min -->
        <TextBox Name="Min_1" Text=""/>
        <TextBox Name="Min_1" Text=""/>
        <TextBox Name="Min_2" Text=""/>
        <TextBox Name="Min_3" Text=""/>
        <TextBox Name="Min_4" Text=""/>

        <!-- Value -->
        <TextBlock Name="vlu_1"/>
        <TextBlock Name="vlu_1"/>
        <TextBlock Name="vlu_2"/>
        <TextBlock Name="vlu_3"/>
        <TextBlock Name="vlu_4"/>

        <!-- Max -->
        <TextBox Name="txtMax_1" Text=""/>
        <TextBox Name="txtMax_1" Text=""/>
        <TextBox Name="txtMax_2" Text=""/>
        <TextBox Name="txtMax_3" Text=""/>
        <TextBox Name="txtMax_4" Text=""/>
```

Within my `C#` code, the `vlu_#` is updated every 5 seconds, but this shouldn't affect what I need.

So to break down, I need a way that once I hit the `enter` key, the value of `vlu_1` etc will change straight away

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to just use the KeyDown event on the textbox to trigger your 'commit' code when enter is pressed.

```
<TextBox Name="txtMin_1" Text="" Width="20" Margin="193,34,223,134" KeyDown="txtMin_1_KeyDown"/>
```

and then in code

```
private void txtMin_1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            //commit code here
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's giving me an error on the `if (e.Key` line, saying that Key doesn't exist in the current context

Comment: You need to have `using System.Windows.Input;` to recognize Key.Enter part.  if it's the `e.Key` part you quote then what do you have e defined as?

Comment: Nothing yet as I'm trying to work out how to enter the variables for it. I'm using what you provided, and the in `commit code here` I'm adding in the code that changed the value of vlu_1 to the value inside txtmin_1

Comment: I realised my error. Saying that KeyEventArgs does not contain a definition for 'Key' (etc etc), and subsequently, the other error is 'Key' does not exist in the current context. The underline is below both `key`s in the line `if (e.Key == Key.Enter)`